# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?) even with adding this permission in android manifest

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I know many others ask similar question before. But I ducked this a lot but my problem didn't solve with previous answers on the stackoverflow or another websites:
this is my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and I have this code in my class:

```
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://sirsaleh.com/atu/atu.php", "GET", params);
```

But I see this runtime error each time:

```
09-28 16:22:28.579    9558-9597/ir.atue.atufeed E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:612)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:495)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:473)
        at ir.atue.atufeed.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:65)
        at ir.atue.atufeed.takeit$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(takeit.java:106)
        at ir.atue.atufeed.takeit$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(takeit.java:84)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
        at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:612)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:495)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:473)
            at ir.atue.atufeed.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:65)
            at ir.atue.atufeed.takeit$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(takeit.java:106)
            at ir.atue.atufeed.takeit$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(takeit.java:84)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Please post your entire manifest. See also [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html).

Comment: Thanks for your link! problem exactly was "You Have the Element in the Wrong Place" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your permission in the manifest this way:

```
<manifest ... >

 ...

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

 <application ...

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!! I wrote my permissions it in <application></application> tag before! But I should use it before opening <application> thanks really! You saved me!

Answer (score 1):

The device you run the app on (emulator, android phone, etc.) probably has no access to the network address you defined in your code.

> Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No
>   address associated with hostname)

As you get the error above, try to open the http address with your device's native browser and make sure your device has access to that address. Otherwise, maybe you should check your device's internet connection and proxy settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But Problem was in my androidmanifest file :)